# How do I load a MS Word HTML document containing images into a WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

1. I have a Word doc with text and images (screenshots)
2. I saved the file as HTM
3. I saved the file in one of my DOC libraries
4. I went to SharePoint and used a webpart (Content Editor/file) to
   reference the    htm doc now found in my Doc library

All the text was viewable, but not the images.  I noticed MS Word saves the images off to a folder when you convert to HTM.

How do I get the images to be viewable within the document when it is within SharePoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed MS Word saves the images off to a folder when you convert to
>   HTM.

May be answer is in your question! So check the image path after converting it to htm. If MS word saves images to folder called "Web Part Images", then check the `src` of your all `<img>` tag. This folder name must be with image path. `src` should look like following

```
/LibraryName/FolderName/FileName.extension
```